# Would allowing familiars outside the ones described in Find Familiar cause problems?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, familiars

I plan on running a 5e campaign sometime soon, and I'm not very familiar (pun intended) with the rules and implications of the Find Familiar spell.

In the past, I've run 3.5e campaigns and had characters ask for special familiars, for example one chose a butterfly, and another a turtle. In my first 5e campaign, a character wants to have a rabbit familiar.

My question is: Does this impose any specific problems? Is there a specific balance problem that would arise if the limited the selection of 15 familiars in the spell description would be expanded?

Just for clarification, I'm looking for an answer about any sort of custom familiar, not just the rabbit.

When I say "any sort of custom familiar" I mean "custom familiars in general." I know that a dragon or a sphinx would not make a good familiar, I just want to know if *a* custom familiar could be made, or if even one custom familiar breaks a balance rule I'm not experienced enough to notice.

Comment: You might consider reworking this question to avoid designer reasons as it has been a hotly debated subject in the Meta. Perhaps asking on whether substitutions are balanced based on answerer experience as an example.

Comment: @Slagmoth just did that

Comment: Why not just ask about the rabbit familiar? That is what the player wants so it seems like that is your specific issue right now, correct? We do much better with handling actual specific problems as opposed to theoretical general ones. Would you consider changing the question to just be about the rabbit? Or maybe explain why your problem would be solved by asking about all of them?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Because I wanted to be able to determine if there was innately a problem with adding more familiar options to the game. A rabbit is a very simple one, and just an example to illustrate my point. I also want to know in the future in case a friend wants to play with like, a scorpion familiar, or a starfish familiar, or a more unusual animal.

Comment: @NoelleB: So is the question you really want answered: "How can I determine if a custom familiar form is balanced?" or maybe "How can I allow my players to choose custom familiar forms but keep the game balanced?"?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Not really, I just wanted to know if custom familiars in and of themselves would create a huge balance problem that a relatively new DM wouldn't see without experience. I think I've got my answer down below.

Comment: The problem is that the answer to that question depends on the type of familiar. Having an elder wyrm fire dragon as a custom familiar is slightly different from having a rabbit as a custom familiar in terms of potential balance problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

D&D 5th edition takes a very literal interpretation of the rules. If the rules say the *find familiar* spell only lets you choose from one of fifteen animals, then that's how the rule is interpreted.

*However*, the DM can always override any rule, especially if the player has something they want to pick. This has been true in every edition of D&D, and is explicitly stated in page 4 of the 5th edition Dungeon Master's Guide:

> The D&D rules help you and the other players have a good time, but the rules aren't in charge. You're the DM, and *you* are in charge of the game.

There's nothing to prevent the DM from allowing a player to choose another familiar, provided that it is within the approximate same power level range as the standard options.

We often saw this in D&D 3.5, where various books provided numerous additional options for familiars. There's nothing special about the standard familiar list other than that they lie within a certain power range, and there's nothing overpowered about allowing other creatures of similar power level.

Something you might also do is to reskin an existing familiar, that is to say, to use the game stats for one animal as another. This ensures that the new familiar is not overpowered. It's simply a matter of asking the DM to make an exception for you.

Comment: There's precedent for expanding the list - Fai Chen's Fantastic Faire, a source of special items in DDAL play, has certs allowing other choices. If there isn't an available stat block, they use an existing one with modifications if required.

Comment: One of the reasons it's limited to these creatures is also because these are creatures that _have_ statblocks. There's not enough room in the Player's Handbook to include all possible familiars.

Comment: Well, for one, *I* would be the DM in this campaign.

Comment: @NoelleB is there a particular balance concern you have with another familiar form or is it just about the increased versatility?

Comment: @DavidCoffron I'm not experienced enough with the power/balance levels of 5e to make that kind of call, so I came here for a more educated answer.

Comment: Are you looking at refluffing an existing stat block, or using a new stat block?

Answer (score 7):

## RAW, obviously does not allow this, but...

You are empowered and encouraged as the DM to make a game everyone enjoys. There is freedom and responsibility to that. Allowing a critter that the player wants to be their familiar is a great way to keep them engaged.

If you don't feel comfortable evaluating the balance of a homebrewed statblock for that critter, simply take a stat block of one of the allowed familiars and re-title it. I think the Cat stat-block could very very easily be mapped to a Rabbit, with a simple change of claw attack to bite attack and keen smell to keen hearing. A Turtle could use a Lizard statblock, etc.

Comment: The physical description of the Rabbit would have to also include 'big, nahsty teeth!'

Comment: @MarsJarsGuitars-n-Chars "Big, sharp, pointy teeth!"